# Checkbox enable/disable file upload. When checkbox is not checked the file on record getting deleted

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry, now I have another problem: if the checkbox is unchecked I want the file on record to stay but every time after submit the file is getting erased from the database. Can someone help please? My code is at [JSFiddle] (jsfiddle.net/sc6ksu0m/87) 87

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to include all relevant information in this question. It sounds like this problem is related to one you had before. Then link to the old problem, but make sure that your new question can be understood on it's own. As you can see, the link to your fiddle is not formatted correctly - try removing the space before the `(`. Also, you should add relevant code to your question as well, and not just keep it on an external site.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I joined very recently and am still learning how to use the site.

Comment: But I was able to fix the problem by not disabling the current value box.

Comment: Here is the fiddle code (http://jsfiddle.net/sc6ksu0m/89) 89

Comment: No problem! Instead of adding new information in comments, it is prefereable to edit your original question. Also, if you solved your problem it is great if you post an answer to your own question explaining how you did it, so future visitors might be helped.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. I do not know if this the best solution but it is working the way I want.
Here is the code:

HTML CODE:

```
Abstract: 
<br>
<input name="abstract" type="text" size="40" class="style5" value="<? echo "$info[abstract]";?>"/  >
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="confirm">
</label>
<input name="abstract" type="file" id="abstract" size="30" class="style5" disabled / onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);">
<br>
<span class="formnotes">(Current value)</span> <br> 
<br> 

Previous Paper or Poster: 
<br> 
<input name="poster" type="text" size="40" class="style5" value="<? echo "$info[poster]";?>"/>

<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="confirmp">
</label>
<input name="poster" type="file" id="poster" size="30" class="style5" disabled / onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);">
<br> 
<span class="formnotes">(Current value)</span>
<br>

Resume: 
<br> 
<input name="resume" type="text" size="40" class="style5" value="<? echo "$info[resume]";?>"/>

<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="confirmr">
</label>
<input name="resume" type="file" id="resume" size="30" class="style5" disabled / onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);">
<br> 
<span class="formnotes">(Current value)</span> <br>
```

And here is JavaScrip Code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.onload = function() {
var checker = document.getElementById('confirm');
var sbm_abstract = document.getElementById('abstract');
var checkerp = document.getElementById('confirmp');
var sbm_poster = document.getElementById('poster');
var checkerr = document.getElementById('confirmr');
var sbm_resume = document.getElementById('resume');


checker.onchange = function () {
if(this.checked) {
    sbm_abstract.disabled = false;
} 
else {
    sbm_abstract.disabled = true;

}
} ;



checkerp.onchange = function () {
if(this.checked) {
    sbm_poster.disabled = false;
} 
else {
    sbm_poster.disabled = true;

}
}; 

checkerr.onchange = function () {
if(this.checked) {
    sbm_resume.disabled = false;
} 
else {
    sbm_resume.disabled = true;

}
}; 

};      </script>
```